# svg "g" element dimensions stuck on 0 (auto)

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to create something on JSfiddle regarding a question about d3, but I was ambushed by an unexpected problem - the "`g`" element I am creating inside an "`svg`" is refusing to accept any dimensions I give it!

I have tried using inline styling, classes (including "`!important`"), but nothing seems to work. The dimensions are stuck at `0,0` and inspection shows width and height are "`auto`" (why?!)

This seems like a trivial issue but for the life of me I can't seem to get the "`g`" element to accept width and height values

see JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sangil/uKLU3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<g>` is an autosizing container. It has no dimensions itself but instead it always automatically sizes itself to contain all its contents.

The reason you're not seeing anything is that SVG (unlike html) does not size things using styles but using attributes instead. So you want

```
g.append("rect")
    .attr("width", "300px")
    .attr("height", "200px")
    .style("fill", "steelblue");
```

Comment: but it has contents - the "rect" element I have placed inside.

Comment: Yes but the size of the rect is 0 because you didn't create it right.